# Any much faster methods for clustering than K means?

Tags: opencv, scikit-learn, k-means

I have handwritten digit in a box and I'm trying to just pull the handwritten digit out. The size is 208 x 117, so that's about 24k pixels.

[image]

I want to take advantage of the fact that I have color, so I decided to use a clustering algorithm to isolate the color of the digit, then extract just those pixels. The problem is that I need to get this down to 0.01s per digit, and now `sklearn.cluster.KMeans` takes about 0.15s. I tried resizing the image, but that takes time in itself, and I also tried using a threshold to just get the colored pixels and ignore the light background (gets me down to 10k pixels), but that didn't speed things up much.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a way. Turns out you get a massive speedup by reducing sample size. So I just randomly sampled a quarter of the pixels and fed that into the clustering function. I got a 50x speedup.